# Javascript convert stringified array of objects into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have the following variable (given to me through a HTTP response, hence the string):

```
var result = '[{name: "John"}, {name: "Alice"}, {name: "Lily"}]'
```

In reality there are more objects and each object has more properties, but you get the idea.

When trying `JSON.parse(result)` I get the following error:

```
[{name: "John"}, {name: "Alice"}, {name: "Lily"}]
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
```

How can I parse this string into an array of javascript objects?

Comment: it's not a valid JSON

Comment: keys should be in quotes like [{"name": "John"}...

Comment: you could do `var result = eval(yourString);` if you really don't care about the [downsides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not valid JSON. In order for it to be valid JSON, you would need to have quotes around the keys ("name")

```
[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Alice"}, {"name": "Lily"}]
```

The error occurs because the parser does not hit a `"` and instead hits the `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your string is not valid JSON (it lacks quotes around property keys), you cannot parse it using `JSON.parse`. If you can control the response, you should change it to return:

```
[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Alice"}, {"name": "Lily"}]
```

---

### Working Demo:

```js
var result = '[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Alice"}, {"name": "Lily"}]'

console.log(JSON.parse(result))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input format is rigid, parsing is trivial.

```
function cutSides(s) { return s.substring(1, s.length - 1); }
var pairs = cutSides(result).split(', ');
var list_of_objects = pairs.map(function(s) { 
    var pair = cutSides(s).split(': ');
    var result = {};
    result[pair[0]] = cutSides(pair[1]); 
    return result;
});
```